# Uploading Firmware to Atmega1284p using ESP8266 with AVRISP as programmer

Tags: esp8266, avr, avrdude

I am trying to flash a new Firmware to my Ender 3 Pro.

I am using the ESP8266 as an ISP via AVRISP over Wifi.

I have a 10mF capacitor between the ground and reset of the ESP8266

I followed this thread: [ESP8266 as ISP program for ATMega16](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/44702/esp8266-as-isp-program-for-atmega16?newreg=af926103f4bd475dba01b4dada1ea79b)

When uploading I get the following output on console:

```
C:\Users\Chry>"I:\3dPrints\Firmware Pack Source Folder\Windows Arduino\hardware\tools\avr/bin/avrdude" -C "I:\3dPrints\Firmware Pack Source Folder\Windows Arduino\hardware\tools\avr/etc/avrdude.conf"
-v -V -p atmega1284p -c arduino -P net:192.168.178.59:328 -b 115200 -D -U flash:w:C:\Users\Chry\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino_build_166520/TH3DUF_R2.ino.hex:i

avrdude: Version 6.3-20171130
         Copyright (c) 2000-2005 Brian Dean, http://www.bdmicro.com/
         Copyright (c) 2007-2014 Joerg Wunsch

         System wide configuration file is "I:\3dPrints\Firmware Pack Source Folder\Windows Arduino\hardware\tools\avr/etc/avrdude.conf"

         Using Port                    : net:192.168.178.59:328
         Using Programmer              : arduino
         Overriding Baud Rate          : 115200
avrdude: ser_drain(): read error: Falscher Parameter.

avrdude: ser_drain(): read error: Falscher Parameter.

avrdude: ser_drain(): read error: Falscher Parameter.

         AVR Part                      : ATmega1284P
         Chip Erase delay              : 55000 us
         PAGEL                         : PD7
         BS2                           : PA0
         RESET disposition             : dedicated
         RETRY pulse                   : SCK
         serial program mode           : yes
         parallel program mode         : yes
         Timeout                       : 200
         StabDelay                     : 100
         CmdexeDelay                   : 25
         SyncLoops                     : 32
         ByteDelay                     : 0
         PollIndex                     : 3
         PollValue                     : 0x53
         Memory Detail                 :

                                  Block Poll               Page                       Polled
           Memory Type Mode Delay Size  Indx Paged  Size   Size #Pages MinW  MaxW   ReadBack
           ----------- ---- ----- ----- ---- ------ ------ ---- ------ ----- ----- ---------
           eeprom        65    10   128    0 no       4096    8      0  9000  9000 0xff 0xff
           flash         65    10   256    0 yes    131072  256    512  4500  4500 0xff 0xff
           lock           0     0     0    0 no          1    0      0  9000  9000 0x00 0x00
           lfuse          0     0     0    0 no          1    0      0  9000  9000 0x00 0x00
           hfuse          0     0     0    0 no          1    0      0  9000  9000 0x00 0x00
           efuse          0     0     0    0 no          1    0      0  9000  9000 0x00 0x00
           signature      0     0     0    0 no          3    0      0     0     0 0x00 0x00
           calibration    0     0     0    0 no          1    0      0     0     0 0x00 0x00

         Programmer Type : Arduino
         Description     : Arduino

avrdude: stk500_getparm(): (a) protocol error, expect=0x14, resp=0x14

avrdude: stk500_getparm(): (a) protocol error, expect=0x14, resp=0x10
         Hardware Version: 4744608
         Firmware Version: 0.2
         Topcard         : STK502
         Vtarget         : 1.8 V
         Varef           : 0.0 V
         Oscillator      : Off
         SCK period      : 0.1 us

avrdude: stk500_initialize(): (b) protocol error, expect=0x10, resp=0x01
avrdude: initialization failed, rc=-1
         Double check connections and try again, or use -F to override
         this check.

avrdude: stk500_disable(): protocol error, expect=0x14, resp=0x10

avrdude done.  Thank you.
```

I can't seem to get it to work. Does anyone have any ideas?

I tried programming it directly:
I use the standard Arduino ISP sketch on my ESP8266 and try to upload that way. Directly connected the ESP8266 to my computer. I get sync-problems now: avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 9 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x61
The Board in the arduino IDE is set to Sanguino 1284p and the programmer is set to Arduino as ISP.

Comment: I have a 10mF capacitor between the ground and reset of the ESP8266. I'll edit that info in the question as well.

Comment: found this ... https://github.com/arduino/Arduino/issues/730

Comment: That goes beyond my understanding. I changed plans though. I use the standard Arduino ISP sketch on my ESP8266 and try to upload that way. Directly connected the ESP8266 to my computer. I get sync-problems now: avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 9 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x61

Comment: you are not alone https://github.com/esp8266/Arduino/issues/6517#issuecomment-531480035 I will try it today. I tested it in Jan 2018 and it worked then

Comment: https://github.com/esp8266/Arduino/issues/6519#issuecomment-531551733

Comment: 10milliFarad, or 10microFarad?  0.1microFarad is generally used when you are trying to create a Reset pulse for serial downloads. For programming via the SPI pins - SCK, MOSI, MISO - Reset is controlled directly.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you have to wrap the directory in the option `-U flash:w:C:\Users\Chry\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino_build_166520/TH3DUF_R2.ino.hex:i` with `"`s. I don't promise that it'll work with that change, but `C:\Users...` will definitely confuse the parser due to the `:`!